# How to set timer in react-navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I tried navigate react-native-navigation with timer. So if the value of the timer is '5', navigation to 'Home' is called.

I used ternary operation to call navigation.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button
} from 'react-native';
import {styles} from './AppStyle'
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'
import HomeScreen from './Pages/Home'

class Timer extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
      this.state = {
        time : props.count
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.addInterval = setInterval( () => this.increase(), 1000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    clearInterval(this.addInterval)
  }

  increase(){
    this.setState((_state, _props) => ({
      time: parseInt(this.state.time) + 1
    }))
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Text> {this.state.time} </Text>
    );
  }

}
class StartScreen extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.navbar}>
          <Timer count='0'/>
          {this.props.count == '5' ? ()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : ''}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };
}

const HomeNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen
    }
  }
)

const StartNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Start: {
      screen: StartScreen
    },
    Main: {
      screen: HomeNavigator
    }    
  },
  {
    mode: 'modal',
    headerMode: 'none'
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Start'
  }
)

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(StartNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer/>
  }
}
```

I expect when count is '5' screen will navigate to 'Home', but i got this issue "Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: Text Strings must be rendered within a  component"

Comment: Is the 'count' value output correctly?

Comment: this line => `{this.props.count == '5' ?()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : ''}` shouldn't be called inside the render. You must re-consider that logic and execute it inside the `setInterval` callback. I think that this is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Create an `onIncrease` prop for your `Timer` component, rather than directly making the function call within `render`.

```js
class Timer extends React.Component {
  /* component functions */

  increase = () => {
    const { time } = this.state
    const { onIncrease } = this.props
    const newTime = time + 1
    onIncrease(newTime)
    this.setState({ time: newTime })
  }

  /* render function */
}

class StartScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.navbar}>
          <Timer
            count={0}
            onIncrease={count => {
              if (count === 5) {
                this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
              }
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `setTimeout`, instead of doing:

```
{this.props.count == '5' ? ()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('Home') : ''}
```

you can do

```
{ setTimeout(()=>{ this.props.navigation.navigate("Home") }, 3000);}
```